# Smartphone spyware and password alias

Tags: smartphone, spyware

I got a phone as a gift from a company. The company makes smartphones (for example, say Apple) and specializes on topics that I work on at another company.

1. What are the chances that they might have installed spy software on it? 
   The phone came of course sealed and brand new.
2. To connect to our wifi, I need to enter my password. The password is however my email password (namely, account password). Can I create an alias to my password? By that I mean, you create a string, say mystring, which is a kind of a symbolic link to your password, but your email/account work only under the actual password.
3. How can I rule out having spyware installed on this smartphone?

Comment: Have you talked to your company's IT and security departments? They will probably have an opinion on this, and will be the ones equipped to create any secondary passwords or other similar countermeasures.